# Angular2 - TypeScript : Increment a number after timeout in AppComponent

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to create a simple `Angular2` Application using `TypeScript`. Seems, pretty simple, but I am not able to achieve what I wanted to.

I want to show a property value in the template. And I want to update the same after 1 second using setTimeout.

Plunkr Code is here : [Code on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RhYhVS84wnOdPuhYUG1E?p=preview)

What I wrote is here :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`<h1>Number Increment</h1><p>{{n}}</p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public n : number = 1;
  setTimeout(function() {
    n = n + 10;
  }, 1000);
}
```

When I use this code I am getting following error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Why I am not able to access `n`, which is in the same scope as we used to do in JavaScript. If I am not wrong, we can use pure JavaScript too in TypeScript.

I even tried

```
export class AppComponent {
  public n : number = 1;
  console.log(n);
}
```

But I am not able to see the value of `n` in the console.

When I tried

```
export class AppComponent {
  public n : number = 1;
  console.log(this);
}
```

I am getting same error as above. Why cant we access this in this place. I guess, `this` refers to the current context as in JavaScript.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This is not valid TypeScript code. You can not have method invocations in the body of a class.

```js
// INVALID CODE
export class AppComponent {
  public n: number = 1;
  setTimeout(function() {
    n = n + 10;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Instead move the `setTimeout` call to the `constructor` of the class. Additionally, use the arrow function `=>` to gain access to `this`.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public n: number = 1;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.n = this.n + 10;
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

In TypeScript, you can only refer to class properties or methods via `this`. That's why the arrow function `=>` is important.

Comment: Thanks  @toskv It worked. Actually `this` reference was not working inside `setTimeout` function. For that I had to use `that` and `this` as given at [Updated Plunkr Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/RhYhVS84wnOdPuhYUG1E?p=preview)

Comment: You should use arrow function. They allow you to use the ***this*** keyword without having to store it in another variable. (eg: `setTimeout(() => { this.n += 10; }, 1000);`

Comment: I updated the answer to use an arrow function so this works fine in setTimeout as well. :)

Comment: @Romain, Thanks for the arrow function. It is really useful in this.

Comment: Eventually, try to move the code into Angulars ngOnInit lifecycle hook to keep the constructor clean. That makes testing a lot easier.

Answer (score 7):

You should put your processing into the class constructor or an `OnInit` hook method.